# Problem using Curl to login to NYTimes.com

Tags: php, curl, login-script

**UPDATE:** Turns out my code works. Browser was caching previous failed response. Thanks for the pointers.

I'm building a prototype and one thing I'd like to do is perform a service if the user is a valid member of NYTimes.com by providing their credentials.

Using curl, I'm trying to perform a login to the site, and then check for success or failure.

My code, below, doesn't return errors but drops me back at the login page:

```
<?php
class Login {

    function Verify() {
        print $this->getContent();
    }

    function getContent() {

        $url    = 'http://www.nytimes.com/auth/login';

        // URI can be any NYT web page to be redirected to upon successful login
        // SAVEOPTION and Submit2 are Optional but in original web form so included here

        $fields = array(
            'is_continue'=> 'true',
            'USERID'     => urlencode('ENTER_YOUR_USERNAME'),
            'PASSWORD'   => urlencode('ENTER_A_PASSWORD'),
            'URI'        => urlencode('http://www.nytimes.com/robots.txt'), 
            'OQ'         => '',
            'OP'         => '',
            'SAVEOPTION' => 'YES',
            'Submit2'    => 'Log In'
        );

        $fields_string = '';

        if(!$curld = curl_init($url)) {
            echo "Could not connect to the specified resource";
               exit;
        }
        $ch        = curl_init();
        $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; } 
        rtrim($fields_string,'&');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "curl_login_cookie.txt");

        curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

        ob_start();
        curl_exec ($ch);

        curl_close ($ch);
        $result = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $result;
    }
}

$login  = new Login;
$result = $login->Verify();
?>
```

Any pointers, or suggestions welcome.

Comment: Why would a user want to give you their nytimes.com credentials?

Comment: Does curl do post?  I'm no PHP or Curl master, but I thought it was get only.

Comment: @tster curl definitely can POST.

Comment: @Daniel - A user will give me their credentials cos I'm going to ask them very nicely and provide a better user-experience and more data if they do.

Comment: @Michael that's fine and all, but in general, users with some concept of security would be very wary of giving up their password to an unrelated site, even if you have the best intentions.

Comment: @Daniel - Ah I see. In that case I'm happy to report that I work for said website and building a prototype outside our typical dev environments.

Comment: @Michael you work on nytimes.com? In that case, can't you just access the database directly?

Comment: @Daniel - Normally yes, but as I said I'm working on a prototype on a box outside the network. When its ready for staging/production I would then switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the result of [`curl_exec`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) is not false (which it'll be if the execution failed).

If it's succeeding, try checking the results of [`curl_errno`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) and [`curl_getinfo`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to see information about the operation.

Also, it might be better to set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option on your curl object instead of using output buffering to capture the result.